# Error changing provider to MSOLEDBSQL in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, oledb

i am trying to set the provider to MSOLEDBSQL using the crystal decisions SDK. Below is the code that i am using to this task. When i run this code crystal report is throwing "Failed to retrieve data from the database. The crystal report calls a stored procedure which is logged in the database but the stored procedure is called without the "exec" keyword in trace log . Below i have copied the how the stored procedure call looks like. Is there any change needed to the SetLogonInfo to make the crystal report work with MSOLEDBSQL provider

```
"stprs_sample_stored_procedure";1 CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-03-01 00:00:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-04-23 00:00:00', 120), '*', 'N'



private void SetLogonInfo(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables tables, string serverName,
            string databaseName, string userName, string password)
        {
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                PropertyBag QELogonProperties = new PropertyBagClass() as PropertyBag;
                QELogonProperties.Add("Application Intent", "READWRITE");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Auto Translate", "-1");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Connect Timeout", "15");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Data Source", serverName);
                QELogonProperties.Add("DataTypeCompatibility", "0");
                QELogonProperties.Add("General Timeout", "0");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Initial Catalog", databaseName);
                QELogonProperties.Add("Integrated Security", "False");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Locale Identifier", "1033");
                QELogonProperties.Add("MARS Connection", "0");
                QELogonProperties.Add("OLE DB Services", "-5");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Provider", "MSOLEDBSQL");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Tag with column collation when possible", "0");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Trust Server Certificate", "0");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Use DSN Default Properties", "False");
                QELogonProperties.Add("Use Encryption for Data", "0");

                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Application Intent", "READWRITE");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Auto Translate", "-1");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Connect Timeout", "15");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Data Source", serverName);
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("DataTypeCompatibility", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("General Timeout", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Initial Catalog", databaseName);
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Integrated Security", "False");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Locale Identifier", "1033");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("MARS Connection", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("OLE DB Services", "-5");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Provider", "MSOLEDBSQL");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Tag with column collation when possible", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Trust Server Certificate", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Use DSN Default Properties", "False");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Use Encryption for Data", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("MultiSubnetFailover", "0");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("TransparentNetworkIPResolution", "-1");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Use FMTONLY", "-1");
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("Database DLL", "crdb_ado.dll"));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseName", databaseName));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseType", "OLE DB (ADO)"));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_ServerDescription", serverName));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_SQLDB", "True"));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("SSO Enabled", "False"));
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_LogonProperties", QELogonProperties));

                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userName;
                logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password.Decrypted(userName);

                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
            }
        }
```